# Python проверка режима мышки для левши

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

Задача в автоматизации: определить настроена ли мышка на левую руку.

Сталкивался кто?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pyautogui` не различает, выдержка из документации гласит:

```
If the buttons are swapped, the primary button is the right mouse button and the secondary button is the left mouse button.  
If not swapped, the primary and secondary buttons are the left and right buttons, respectively.

NOTE: Swap detection has not been implemented yet.
```

Распознование еще не реализовано.

НО для windows можно забрать информацию из `GetSystemMetrics`. [Здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) можно посмотреть для возможных значений. Нам нужен `SM_SWAPBUTTON` и адрес `0x0017`.

Теперь можно написать коротенькую функцию для опредления левши:

```py
import ctypes

def is_left():
    get_state = 23 #0x0017 for SM_SWAPBUTTON
    is_left_from_win = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(get_state)
    return bool(is_left_from_win)
```

вызов функции будет возвращать `True`, если пользователь левша

```py
>>> is_left()
False
```

Переключим в винде и попробуем

```py
>>> is_left()
True
```

Так же можно через стороннюю библиотеку `pywin32`.

Для Linux такую функцию написал:

```py
import subprocess
import re
def is_left():
  retval = subprocess.Popen("xmodmap -pp", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
  data = retval.decode().split("\n")
  for i in data:
    k = i.split()
    if len("".join(k)) == 2:
      if k[0] != k[1]:
         return True
  return False
```

[`xmodmap утилитой`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-xmodmap/) можно прочитать как определены соответствия физических кнопок и логических. Для правши это выглядит вот так:

```
~$ xmodmap -pp
There are 10 pointer buttons defined.

    Physical        Button
     Button          Code
        1              1
        2              2
        3              3
        4              4
        5              5
        6              6
        7              7
        8              8
        9              9
       10             10
```

для левши вот так

```
~$ xmodmap -pp
There are 10 pointer buttons defined.

    Physical        Button
     Button          Code
        1              3
        2              2
        3              1
        4              4
        5              5
        6              6
        7              7
        8              8
        9              9
       10             10
```

И в функции просто сравнил значения колонок. Если хоть одно сравнение дает `False`, значит левша трогает мышку